# Would this modification accelerate convergence of generalized linear model, or break it?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, inference, link-function, irls

[This page](https://bwlewis.github.io/GLM/) describes the following iteratively reweighted linear least-squares (IRLS) method for solving a generalized linear model (GLM):

> 1. let $x_1=0$
> 2. for $j=1,2,...$ do
>
>    - linear predictor: let $\eta=Ax_j$
>    - Newton-method correction: let $z=\eta+\frac{b-g(\eta)}{g'(\eta)}$
>    - reweighting: let $W = \text{diag}(g'(\eta)^2/\text{var}(g(\eta)))$
>    - solve linear least-squares: let $x_{j+1}=(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWz$
>    - stop if $||x_{j+1}-x_j||$ is sufficiently small

where $b$ is the response vector and $g$ is the inverse link function (i.e. $g^{-1}$ is the link function)

(Note that this naming is consistent with the [link above](https://bwlewis.github.io/GLM/) but opposite to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function)'s convention, where $g$ is the link function and $g^{-1}$ is the inverse link function.).

But why does step 2.2 (Newton-method correction) not simply do $z=g^{-1}(b)$ instead? The algorithm would obviously still have the same stationary point, and surely get there faster?

## Edit

So the algorithm I am proposing would be:

> 1. let $z=g^{-1}(b)$
> 2. let $\eta=z$
> 3. for $j=1,2,...$ do
>
>    - reweighting: let $W = \text{diag}(g'(\eta)^2/\text{var}(g(\eta)))$
>    - solve linear least-squares: let $x_{j}=(A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWz$
>    - linear predictor: let $\eta=Ax_j$
>    - stop if $||x_{j}-x_{j-1}||$ is sufficiently small

and now only the weights and linear least-squares solution are being updated with each iteration and we aren't trying to reverse-engineer $g$ at the same time, since $g^{-1}$ is available. Or have I broken it?

Comment: From your reference I understand $b$ to be the response vector, and therefore $z$ is intended to be some vector *of the form $z=Ax.$*  Isn't the entire issue that there usually doesn't exist any vector for which $g(Ax)=b$? How, then, could your algorithm possibly converge at all?

Comment: @whuber Yes of course; thank you.